# Apache won't answer request for some IP

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I'm running Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Server behind NAT. Some people are not able to load web pages.

Here is the Wireshark capture of a failed request:

```
188.231.225.211 -> 192.168.2.4  HTTP 579 GET / HTTP/1.1
192.168.2.4 -> 188.231.225.211 HTTP 348 HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
188.231.225.211 -> 192.168.2.4  HTTP 600 GET /secure/Dashboard.jspa HTTP/1.1
```

and Apache stops responding.

This is another capture which shows normal response:

```
192.168.2.6 -> 192.168.2.4  HTTP 454 GET / HTTP/1.1
192.168.2.4 -> 192.168.2.6  HTTP 512 HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
192.168.2.6 -> 192.168.2.4  HTTP 616 GET /secure/Dashboard.jspa HTTP/1.1
192.168.2.4 -> 192.168.2.6  HTTP 265 HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (text/html)
```

and page is loading.

What can cause this problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: ...what does Apache's logs say is happning for those clients, since it obviously sees the requests?

Comment: Your working example looks interior-interior network, while the other is from the other side of your NAT device. Are others outside the network able to see it properly, or are only inside-network people getting the proper response?

Comment: Yes, others outside the network able to see it properly.

Comment: I can only see this one in log and no errors.

188.231.225.211 - - [10/Feb/2012:16:43:00 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1998

Comment: Is Apache proxying for something else, like TomCat? If so, what does the other server's logs have to say?

Answer (score 0):

Check MTU size for interfaces.